# OEM engine oil alterrnative

Tags: motorcycle, oil

My motorcycles recommended engine oil grade is 10w30 synthetic.I am not happy with the OEM oil and looking for an alternative ,to my surprise there is not even a single manufacturer providing same grade in synthetic.I am able to find mineral and semi synth oil in same same grade i.e 10w30.
For synthetics I have 10w40,10w50,20w50 options available.
Can i switch to semi synth or upgrade to a heavier 10w40 fully synth

Comment: This has been asked before...

Comment: What are you not happy with?

Comment: engine gets heated up quite fast.also i feel change in performance after i have ridden around 100kms

Comment: Is the bike overheating?

Comment: I would not say overheated but just riding around 2 kms it gets very hot that i can feel the heat at my legs. Outside temp is below 30 degrees these days.

Answer (score 1):

Motul makes 10w30 fully synthetic for 4 stroke bikes. It is coded 7100. You csn use semi synthetic unless the manufacturer specifically recommends fully synthetic although it will have some drawback. You can learn more about oil types or whether you can use a heavy oil if you search this site.

Comment: I do not find Motul 10w30 in my country

Comment: If you have any honda dealers around you may ask them if they have any. Large manifacturers sell their oil and at least some hondas use 10w30

Answer (score 1):

First, it would help to know the make/model/year of your bike, and to some degree the environment you ride in. Usually the manufacturer will provide a few different grade options depending on conditions.

That said, in most cases (*not all*) you can use whatever grade of oil is most applicable to your riding conditions. If you're putting around town in a cooler environment you need different oil than if you're desert racing. This tends to be true regardless of the OE spec because they base it off of the most average riding conditions they can expect.

It is important to know what the numbers and ratings of oils are to better determine, for yourself, if it's a good choice to change. [This is a pretty good place to start](https://www.rymax-lubricants.com/blog/what-does-5w-30-actually-mean/).

Now, it has also been common practice to change grades over time, as the engine becomes more "broken-in". [Vavoline](https://www.valvoline.com/about-us/faq/oil-types-weights-and-viscosity-faq) mentions how bearing clearences can change over time.

The safest bet would be to use the oil they spec. Then the next safest is using the same gear from about maker. Then, next down would be using 5w30,and after that using 10w40.

In your specific case, I'm hesitant to say anything definitive without knowing the make/model.

What I will say definitely though, is the engine coming to running temp fast is not an issue (in and of itself), unless it's also overheating or having other issues. You mention a change in performance as well. If the bike is new, you should generally expect some change, and if it has a lot of miles on it, you will also generally get some change. If this change is noticeable in a single ride then there may be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use 5W-30 synthetic. The 5W means the motorcycle engine starts better in the extreme cold. Well, I'm sure you won't be riding your motorcycle in -20 degrees Celsius, so you won't see the benefits of 5W-30 when compared to 10W-30.

There should be no drawback when using 5W-30 at the usual working temperatures of an engine, if the oil is fresh. At the operating temperature, both are SAE 30 assuming the viscosity improvers haven't degraded.

Note a 5W-30 is actually SAE 5 mixed with viscosity improvers, and 10W-30 is actually SAE 10 mixed with viscosity improvers. So just in case the viscosity improvers degrade with time (thus giving you SAE 5 or SAE 10 oil), you'll want to change the oil at some point of time. But that should be obvious anyway; nobody rides with the same oil in for the lifetime of the engine.

I don't see any drawback of using 5W-30 vs 10W-30 assuming you will change the oil before the viscosity improvers degrade.